# Need XSLT transform to count elements returned from applied template

Tags: xml, xslt, counting, muenchian-grouping

I have a very similar problem to this: [Need XSLT transform to remove duplicate elements - sorted by an attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9022980/need-xslt-transform-to-remove-duplicate-elements-sorted-by-an-attribute). I took the solution from the *best answer* and slightly modified it. I have to count the statuses, but taking into account only the latest results.

My template looks like this:

```xml
<xsl:template match='Results/Result' mode='countstatus'>
    <xsl:param name='status' select='"Pass"'/>
    <xsl:for-each select="key('sn-key', SerialNumber)">
        <xsl:sort select='./Date' order='descending'/>
        <xsl:if test='((position() = 1) and (./Status=$status))'>
            <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

I don't want to display all the matched results but only the number of items returned after this template is applied.

My key definition is `<xsl:key name='sn-key' match='Results/Result' use='SerialNumber'/>` and I call this template with `<xsl:apply-templates select='Results/Result[generate-id() = generate-id(key("sn-key", SerialNumber)[1])]' mode='countstatus'/>`.

**EDIT**

With fresh mind I see that my question is a bit unclear. Here are more details.

My input looks like this:

```xml
<Results>
    <Result ID="0">
        <SerialNumber>3333</SerialNumber>
        <Status>Fail</Status>
        <Date>21</Date>
    </Result>
    <Result ID="1">
        <SerialNumber>1111</SerialNumber>
        <Status>Fail</Status>
        <Date>34</Date>
    </Result>
    <Result ID="2">
        <SerialNumber>1111</SerialNumber>
        <Status>Pass</Status>
        <Date>67</Date>
    </Result>
    <Result ID="3">
        <SerialNumber>2222</SerialNumber>
        <Status>Fail</Status>
        <Date>40</Date>
    </Result>
    <Result ID="4">
        <SerialNumber>1111</SerialNumber>
        <Status>Fail</Status>
        <Date>55</Date>
    </Result>
    <Result ID="5">
        <SerialNumber>1111</SerialNumber>
        <Status>Fail</Status>
        <Date>88</Date>
    </Result>
    <Result ID="6">
        <SerialNumber>2222</SerialNumber>
        <Status>Fail</Status>
        <Date>22</Date>
    </Result>
    <Result ID="7">
        <SerialNumber>1111</SerialNumber>
        <Status>Fail</Status>
        <Date>86</Date>
    </Result>
    <Result ID="8">
        <SerialNumber>3333</SerialNumber>
        <Status>Pass</Status>
        <Date>99</Date>
    </Result>
</Results>
```

I would like to count e.g. how many times the `Fail` status occurs, but considering only the latest results for `SerialNumber`. The template I showed earlier displays all the latest results for `SerialNumber` (but for status `Pass`). I would like to display just the number. In example when looking for the number of fails I would like to display `2` instead of `[1111 Fail 88, 2222 Fail 40]`.

My transformation look like this now (but I need something else):

```xml
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:key name='sn-key' match='Results/Result' use='SerialNumber' />

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="Results/Result[generate-id()=generate-id(key('sn-key', SerialNumber)[1])]"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Results/Result">
    <xsl:param name='status' select='"Fail"'/>
    <xsl:for-each select="key('sn-key', SerialNumber)">
        <xsl:sort select="./Date" order="descending"/>
        <xsl:if test='((position() = 1) and (./Status=$status))'>
            <xsl:value-of select="."/><br />
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***---  edited in response to clarification ---***

> I would like to count e.g. how many times the Fail status occurs, but considering only the latest results for SerialNumber.

I believe that translates to:

- group the `Result`s by SerialNumber;
- count the groups whose most recent `Result` has `Status` of "Fail"

The exact method depends on whether the `Result`s are listed in chronological order in the input XML.

If the answer is yes, you can simply modify the Muenchian method to select the **last** (instead of the usual *first*) `Result` in each group, add another predicate to keep only those whose `Status` is "Fail" and count this set. This is a one-liner:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="result-by-sn" match="Result" use="SerialNumber" />

<xsl:template match="/Results">
    <output>
        <xsl:value-of select="count(Result[count(. | key('result-by-sn', SerialNumber)[last()]) = 1][Status='Fail'])"/>
    </output>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

If the answer is no, then you have no choice but to actually perform the grouping, sorting and filtering into a variable, then count the result:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="result-by-sn" match="Result" use="SerialNumber" />

<xsl:template match="/Results">
    <xsl:variable name="temp">
        <xsl:for-each select="Result[count(. | key('result-by-sn', SerialNumber)[1]) = 1]">
            <xsl:for-each select="key('result-by-sn', SerialNumber)">
                <xsl:sort select="Date" order="descending"/>
                <xsl:if test="position()=1 and Status='Fail'">x</xsl:if>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:variable>
    <output>
        <xsl:value-of select="string-length($temp)"/>
    </output>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: What if the group is not sorted (in my case I need to sort by Date first)?

Can you explain what is the input parameter for `count(. | key('record_by_category', category)`?

Comment: I have revised my post based on your clarifications. Hopefully that answers any questions you might have.

Comment: And is it possible to store in the global variable sorted Results and then use the first method? I tried with exslt:node-set() function but it looks like I have some context issue.

Comment: It is possible, but it will be more complex due to the node-set vs. RTF issue. I suggest you post a separate question if you want to go that way and are unable to work it out.

Comment: Can I also ask about short explanation of `<xsl:for-each select="Result[count(. | key('result-by-sn', SerialNumber)[1]) = 1]">` line?

Comment: That's Muenchian grouping. I am using an alternative expression to your `Result[generate-id() = generate-id(key("sn-key", SerialNumber)[1])]`. You will find the explanation in the original article: http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html

Comment: How hard it would be to do a similar think with XLS-FO? I'm trying this and I'm getting `Unknown formatting object "{}output" encountered`.

Comment: @bienieck I don't know how to answer that. I suggest you post a new question with this new problem.

Comment: Ok. Here it is: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68581918/how-to-count-elements-returned-from-applied-template-using-xsl-fo-and-apache-fo