# How to count elements returned from applied template using XSL-FO (and Apache FOP)

Tags: xml, xslt, xsl-fo, muenchian-grouping

I would like to do something similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68211961/need-xslt-transform-to-count-elements-returned-from-applied-template) but using XSL-FO and Apache FOP.

I have xml input like this (exactly like in the linked question):

```xml
<Results>
    <Result ID="0">
        <SerialNumber>3333</SerialNumber>
        <Status>Fail</Status>
        <Date>21</Date>
    </Result>
    <Result ID="1">
        <SerialNumber>1111</SerialNumber>
        <Status>Fail</Status>
        <Date>34</Date>
    </Result>
    <Result ID="2">
        <SerialNumber>1111</SerialNumber>
        <Status>Pass</Status>
        <Date>67</Date>
    </Result>
    <Result ID="3">
        <SerialNumber>2222</SerialNumber>
        <Status>Fail</Status>
        <Date>40</Date>
    </Result>
    <Result ID="4">
        <SerialNumber>1111</SerialNumber>
        <Status>Fail</Status>
        <Date>55</Date>
    </Result>
    <Result ID="5">
        <SerialNumber>1111</SerialNumber>
        <Status>Fail</Status>
        <Date>88</Date>
    </Result>
    <Result ID="6">
        <SerialNumber>2222</SerialNumber>
        <Status>Fail</Status>
        <Date>22</Date>
    </Result>
    <Result ID="7">
        <SerialNumber>1111</SerialNumber>
        <Status>Fail</Status>
        <Date>86</Date>
    </Result>
    <Result ID="8">
        <SerialNumber>3333</SerialNumber>
        <Status>Pass</Status>
        <Date>99</Date>
    </Result>
</Results>
```

I would like to create XSL file which will generate XSL-FO to generate PDF (using Apache FOP) in which I will display the following text:

```
Total Quantity: 3
Passed: 1
Failed: 2
```

Those numbers are:

- **Total Quantity** - number of unique serial numbers (in this case: 1111, 2222 and 3333),
- **Passed** - number of passed results but counting only the latest result (the highest `Date`) per unique serial number (in this case only 3333 `SerialNumber` with `Date` 99),
- **Failed** - number of failed results but counting only the latest result (the highest `Date`) per unique serial number (in this case `Date` 88 for 1111 and `Date` 40 for 2222).

In another words I need to count number of results only for the latest `Date` per `SerialNumber`. Results are not sorted.

I tried [solution suggested by michael.hor257k](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68212390/6804613) (which works when I use just xslt to generate html in my browser):

```xml
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="result-by-sn" match="Result" use="SerialNumber" />

<xsl:template match="/Results">
    <xsl:variable name="temp">
        <xsl:for-each select="Result[count(. | key('result-by-sn', SerialNumber)[1]) = 1]">
            <xsl:for-each select="key('result-by-sn', SerialNumber)">
                <xsl:sort select="Date" order="descending"/>
                <xsl:if test="position()=1 and Status='Fail'">x</xsl:if>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:variable>
    <output>
        <xsl:value-of select="string-length($temp)"/>
    </output>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But Apache FOP returns `Unknown formatting object "{}output" encountered` error. How to deal with this error and display my results summary?

---

**EDIT:**

Here is my current xsl file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">

<!-- KEY FOR FINDING UUT RESULTS -->
<xsl:key name="result-by-sn" match="Results/Result" use="SerialNumber"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <fo:root>
            <fo:layout-master-set>
                <fo:simple-page-master master-name="my_page" margin="0.5in">
                    <fo:region-body/>
                </fo:simple-page-master>
            </fo:layout-master-set>
            <fo:page-sequence master-reference="my_page">
                <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">
                    <fo:block>Total Quantity: <xsl:value-of select="count(Results/Result[generate-id() = generate-id(key('result-by-sn', SerialNumber)[1])])"/></fo:block>
                    <fo:block>Passed: <!--<xsl:apply-templates select="Results" mode="count"><xsl:with-param name="status" select="'Pass'"/></xsl:apply-templates>--></fo:block>
                    <fo:block>Failed: <!--<xsl:apply-templates select="Results" mode="count"><xsl:with-param name="status" select="'Fail'"/></xsl:apply-templates>--></fo:block>
                </fo:flow>
            </fo:page-sequence>
        </fo:root>
    </xsl:template>

<!-- TEMPLATE TO COUNT RESULTS -->
<!--<xsl:template match="Results" mode="count">
    <xsl:param name="status" select="'Pass'"/>
    <xsl:variable name="temp">
        <xsl:for-each select="Result[generate-id()=generate-id(key('result-by-sn', SerialNumber)[1])]">
            <xsl:for-each select="key('result-by-sn', SerialNumber)">
                <xsl:sort select="Date" order="descending"/>
                <xsl:if test="position() = 1 and  Status = $status">x</xsl:if>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:variable>
    <output>
        <xsl:value-of select="string-length($temp)"/>
    </output>
</xsl:template>-->

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: XSL-FO is a markup language. You do not "use XSL file with XSL-FO". You use XSL transformation to generate a XSL-FO document which can then be used to generate a PDF document. For this, you need to know (a) what do you want your PDF to look like and (b) how must the XSL-FO document be structured in order to produce the wanted PDF. Only then can you construct the XSLT stylesheet to produce the expected XSL-FO.

Comment: I corrected "use XSL file with XSL-FO" part of my question. Regarding part A: I described it in the question (see bolded part). I have working XSL-FO for layout/sequences/flows but I don't think this is relevant here. For this question I will be happy with the simplest PDF layout. Regarding B: I'm not sure what you mean. I think that is the essence of my question and of course I don't know that (hence the question). I have XML source file and the text I want to display (see above). Now, how to transform XML (using XSLT) into XSL-FO to generate the text I need in my PDF?

Comment: *"I will be happy with the simplest PDF layout."* Good. So post the XSL-FO document that produces such layout. Then we will be able to advise you how to modify the existing XSLT to produce such document.

Comment: "Simplest PDF layout" added to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, assuming you want your XSL transformation to produce a result of:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<fo:root xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
  <fo:layout-master-set>
    <fo:simple-page-master master-name="my_page" margin="0.5in">
      <fo:region-body/>
    </fo:simple-page-master>
  </fo:layout-master-set>
  <fo:page-sequence master-reference="my_page">
    <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">
      <fo:block>Total Quantity: 3</fo:block>
      <fo:block>Passed: 1</fo:block>
      <fo:block>Failed: 2</fo:block>
    </fo:flow>
  </fo:page-sequence>
</fo:root>
```

you can use the following stylesheet:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="result-by-sn" match="Result" use="SerialNumber" />

<xsl:template match="/Results">
    <!-- determine counts -->
    <xsl:variable name="distinct-results" select="Result[count(. | key('result-by-sn', SerialNumber)[1]) = 1]" />
    <xsl:variable name="count-distinct" select="count($distinct-results)" />
    <xsl:variable name="fails">
        <xsl:for-each select="$distinct-results">
            <xsl:for-each select="key('result-by-sn', SerialNumber)">
                <xsl:sort select="Date" order="descending"/>
                <xsl:if test="position()=1 and Status='Fail'">F</xsl:if>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="count-fails" select="string-length($fails)" />
    <!-- output -->
    <fo:root xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
        <fo:layout-master-set>
            <fo:simple-page-master master-name="my_page" margin="0.5in">
                <fo:region-body/>
            </fo:simple-page-master>
        </fo:layout-master-set>
        <fo:page-sequence master-reference="my_page">
            <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">
                <fo:block>
                    <xsl:text>Total Quantity: </xsl:text>
                    <xsl:value-of select="$count-distinct"/>
                </fo:block>
                <fo:block>
                    <xsl:text>Passed: </xsl:text>
                    <xsl:value-of select="$count-distinct - $count-fails"/>
                </fo:block>
                <fo:block>
                    <xsl:text>Failed: </xsl:text>
                    <xsl:value-of select="$count-fails"/>
                </fo:block>
            </fo:flow>
        </fo:page-sequence>
    </fo:root>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: This is clever. Normally I can't assign value to a single variable more than once but here you assign `fails` variable value after `for-each` loop. So, it is clever workaround for counter in XSL. Am I correct?

Comment: Not quite. Each variable is assigned only once. In order to count occurrences of `Fail`, we output an `F` for each such occurrence, then look at the length of the resulting string. This avoids the need to convert the variable to a node-set.