# Challenge with removing duplicate and keeping last line from a nested xml

Tags: xslt, duplicates, xml-parsing, xslt-3.0

My Input

```
<FinInstrmRptgTxRpt> 
<Tx><New><TxId>61810</TxId><ExctgPty>ABC</ExctgPty></New></Tx> 
<Tx><New><TxId>618101</TxId><ExctgPty>ABC</ExctgPty></New></Tx> 
<Tx><New><TxId>61810</TxId><ExctgPty>ABX</ExctgPty></New></Tx> 
<Tx><New><TxId>618102</TxId><ExctgPty>XYZ</ExctgPty></New></Tx> 
<Tx><New><TxId>618102</TxId><ExctgPty>XYZ</ExctgPty></New></Tx> 
<Tx><New><TxId>61810</TxId><ExctgPty>XYZ</ExctgPty></New></Tx>
</FinInstrmRptgTxRpt>
```

Output should look like

```
<FinInstrmRptgTxRpt> 
<Tx><New><TxId>618101</TxId><ExctgPty>ABC</ExctgPty></New></Tx> 
<Tx><New><TxId>618102</TxId><ExctgPty>XYZ</ExctgPty></New></Tx> 
<Tx><New><TxId>61810</TxId><ExctgPty>XYZ</ExctgPty></New></Tx>
</FinInstrmRptgTxRpt>
```

In short I would like to remove duplicates from the xml based on TxId and keep the last line of the duplicate occurrence in the data.

I tried using below code but some reason duplicates (like in Python dataframe keep last)are not removed from the output.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

 <xsl:key name="TxIdKeyList" match="Tx" use="TxId"/>
 
 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
     </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match=
 "Tx[ not( generate-id(current()) 
 = 
            generate-id(
                key('TxIdKeyList', 'TxId')[last()])
            )
      ]"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: "Keep the last line"? Your samples as shown have one or two lines only so don't tell us about lines you want to keep or remove, at least name the XML elements. And it would help us understand the problem if you showed the input data in a well formatted way to easily allow us to spot duplicates. And if you use Python and dataframes, why the XSLT 3 tag?

Comment: See if this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68212390/3016153

Comment: I have now improved readability of the post. Apologies for earlier errors in data. I need to do this because we are not parsing this data in Python so need to do in xslt. I feel I am almost there. Just small bug in generate-id line some where.

Comment: Why are you using Muenchian grouping for this, if it's XSLT 3.0?

Comment: I am not very familiar with xslt, so reading and trying to solve this problem at hand.

Answer (score 0):

`TxId` is not a child of `Tx`. So try `use="New/TxId"` in the xsl:key definition.

Also, I think `key('TxIdKeyList', 'TxId')` should be `key('TxIdKeyList', New/TxId)`

Comment: That has not worked. I think issue is in generate-id

Comment: I found a second bug and updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The key should be `<xsl:key name="TxIdKeyList" match="Tx" use="New/TxId"/>`, the template

```
<xsl:template match="Tx[not(generate-id() = generate-id(key('TxIdKeyList', New/TxId)[last()]))]"/>
```

`current()` in an XSLT 1.0 match pattern is not allowed and the second argument of the `key` function is an XPath expression, usually not a string literal.

Comment: No change in the output, please see below


<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:key name="TxIdKeyList" match="Tx" use="New/TxId"/> 
 <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
     </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="Tx[not(generate-id() = 
 generate-id(key('TxIdKeyList', 'New/TxId')[last()]))]"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>

Comment: @Kal, get some coffee, I posted `<xsl:template match="Tx[not(generate-id() = generate-id(key('TxIdKeyList', New/TxId)[last()]))]"/>` and explained "the second argument the key function is an XPath expression, usually not a string literal", yet you make the same error again in your attempt where you put a meaningless string literal as the second argument of your key call `key('TxIdKeyList', 'New/TxId')`. My suggestion does work: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/eiorv2o, your errors are your own.

Comment: Sorry I tried without quotes before but that did not work hence added single quote thinking function need that. Please see below

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bF2MmYm/1

Comment: @Kal, that is quite a different input with a default namespace declaration changing the scenario. Read up on any answer here how to deal with a default namespace in XSLT 1, then you should know how to adapt the XSLT to the changed input.

Comment: This has helped enormously. Thank you all for your help.

Comment: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bF2MmYm/3 is final version

Comment: @Kal, if you are using XSLT 3 anyway I would suggest to rewrite the `generate-id` based comparison into one using the `is` operator: `<xsl:template match="Tx[not(. is key('TxIdKeyList', New/TxId)[last()])]"/>`